# Writing Files to BEAGLEBONE Partition

Tags: linux, mount, beagleboneblack

I am developing an air quality monitor with a `BeagleBone Black`. I want the end users to simply be able to plug the BeagleBone into their computer and transfer the files from the BeagleBone to their machine through the drive that is mounted when plugged in through USB. My application writes to the `BEAGLEBONE` partition physically located at `/dev/mmcblk0p1` on the BeagleBone Black.

```
root@beaglebone:~# fdisk -l

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048      198655       98304    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          198656     7667711     3734528   83  Linux
```

The `/dev/mmcblk0p1` device is mounted to `/mnt/usb` on the BeagleBone through /etc/fstab with the following settings:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/usb auto auto,rw,sync,user,nofail 0 0
```

When I write a file to this mounted directory (say file.txt) on the BeagleBone, the files don't show up on the mounted partition on my Mac until I unplug the device and plug it back in. Even then, after unplugging and plugging the device back in, the file doesn't contain the contents that were written to the file.

For example:

**On BeagleBone**

```
echo "Hello, World!\n" > /mnt/usb/file.txt
```

**On Mac**

1. No file shows up.
2. Unplug BeagleBone Black. Plug it back in.
3. file.txt shows up under BEAGLEBONE drive
4. Open file.txt
5. file.txt *doesn't* contain "Hello, World!\n" text

I'm sure I am overlooking a configuration option. Could someone please elaborate as to why this is happening? I assume that a buffer is not being properly flushed.

Comment: My BBB mounts /dev/mmcblk0p1 as /media/BEAGLEBONE_ without any modification on /etc/fstab. Please try to delete the mount entry on the fstab and execute 'df -h' after rebooting. Could you find /media/BEAGLEBONE_?

Comment: @tasasaki No such mount exists on bootup. What distribution are you running?

Comment: I'm using Debian Wheezy. https://beagleboard.org/latest-images

Comment: /dev/mmcblk0p1 is your board device block?